# Dependent children deported from in UK visa form

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, deportation

In the general visitor visa for UK form, there is an option named "Dependent children". If you click on it, there is a drop down menu named "Deported from". Can someone explain what to enter in that?
For info, its something like that:

________________________  *

|_____________________v_| << Country deported from

There is no "None" option.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or link?

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Suggest you try again on Monday when they have completed the upgrade.